# Find %20 and replace with - in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, dreamweaver

I have a line of code:

```
mainURL=Sample%20Line%20Of%20Code.php
```

I want to replace the %20 with a dash (-) using Dreamweaver's find and replace
I have tried several variations of:
Find - `mainURL=([^\s]*).php`and `mainURL=([^%20]*).php`
Replace - `mainURL=([^-]*).php`it seems to find my string but literally replaces it with `mainURL=([^-]*).php`I'm fairly new to regular expressions and could use some help.
Thanks in advance - Tom

Comment: Please add sample result for the provided example.

Comment: Why would you use regex if you have an exact match (%20). Regex is a tool for defining variable strings by rules

Comment: @ThomasMoors You are right as for rules, and OP needs to only replace those `%20` when inside `matchURL=\S*\.php` pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `(\G(?!\A)|mainURL=(?=\S*\.php))((?:(?!\.php)\S)*?)%20` 
**Replace with**: `$1$2-`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wib9mX/1).

**Details**

- `(\G(?!\A)|mainURL=(?=\S*\.php))` - Group 1 capturing `mainURL=` that is followed with 0+
  non-whitespace and `.php` substring or the end of the previous match
- `((?:(?!\.php)\S)*?)` - Group 2: any non-whitespace char that is not a starting point for `.php` substring, 0+ repetitions, as few as possible
- `%20` - a literal substring.

Comment: This was a big help and solved my problem, also thanks for the link to regex101, that will help me immensely as a newbie to regex - Tom

Comment: @user1757285 Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).